# How to store a secret key in ASP.NET webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

im required to encrypt/decrypt some data the users enters and display back to the user the cipher text...After some small research i have found found one good tutorial that shows encryption/decryption in a very clear way. (link below)

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-QueryString-Parameter-Values-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

However my concern is in this tutorial he has exposed the private key directly in the code. I know this code will be safe in the back end (will not be exposed to end users). But yet is there a better way to secure/store this key if not is the key secure saving it directly in the back end code?

```
private string Encrypt(string clearText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
    byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return clearText;
}
```

I would like to note i have done some research but as most results were related to "Azure Key vault" which does not work for our case..

Comment: Are you aware that the implementation in the tutorial first sends everything to the server as clear text and then encrypts the posted data on the server and redirects to another page? I think what you are required to do is not that, but to encrypt the data entered by the user on the CLIENT SIDE and send this encrypted information to the server. Am I right?

Comment: I've done this 9 years ago. Here is the FORM posted to the server directly from the BROWSER: 1944218009 816255716 -117323551 -415109081 . . . . . 1246405205 -1206283240 111000558 -413674735

Comment: The implementation uses Tiny-TEA symmetric algorithm and creates a different shared key for each session, therefore you don't have to put that key anywhere in your code.

Comment: @OguzOzgul hi oguz, no i have updated my question. actually i need to return the encrypted data back to the user (cipher text). So encryption is done on the backend.. and  encrypted data will be sent to the frontend

Comment: In that case, I would suggest having the key in your web.config / appSettings section and to use aspnet_regiis to encrypt the whole section. Only administrators on the server and you app will be able to decrypt this section afterwards. For the retrieval part, you just read the setting as usual, the value will automatically be decrypted upon your request `ConfigurationManager.ÀppSettings["myEncryptionKey"]`

Comment: Or you can set it in the windows registry and read it from there, where you can set ACL's to prevent anyone (except administrators) from reading it.

Comment: @OguzOzgul yes, i believe that is what i am looking for!

Comment: If you go with the aspnet_regiis option, please consider reading this and don't look over the configuring the encryption for a server farm part (if you have multiple servers and want to deploy the same web.config file): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/68ze1hb2(v%3Dvs.100)

Comment: @OguzOzgul Thanks i will consider that.